# Detecting UITouch collision with views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch, hittest, touchesmoved

I've got some problems with detecting my touch collision with different views. I have set MyView tag to 1, so in if statement later I am detecting if tag is anything else than 1, to get information, if my finger touched any other view in MyView.

In touchesMoved I am detecting collision of my finger movement on screen like:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];

MyView = [self hitTest:p withEvent:nil];

if(MyView.tag =! 1)
{
 NSLog(@"Other view detected");
}

}
```

This code works fine, until I move my finger faster. I figured, that not all locations are detected if you move finger fast. That is just how framework works. So I was thinking of some other options like Bresenham's line algoritm, to get all locations. But this option is kinda slow, and sometimes also not detecting the other views.

I am working on some project similar to labyrinth game, and I am detecting if my finger hits wall. It's not a game really, but I was thinking to make it with SpriteKit, but it would really be too much work to position all nodes to the right places. 
It is really cool, that I can position views in interface builder, and can build labyrinth with views.

I need a advice, or solution, how should I do this. Is there some other framework, that is returning all positions of finger movement? Or should I really do this with some framework like SpriteKit?

Comment: On iOS 9 you can get a _prediction_ of where the touch _will_ move to. You might be able to take advantage of this to "fill in the gaps" when moving fast.

Comment: @matt really? and how can you make that predictions?

Comment: You don't make it. You get it.

Comment: UIEvent `predictedTouchesForTouch:`.